# Validation for phone number in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am new to iOS.

I have created a UITextField and I want to give validations for phone number so that only numbers must be allowed.
If any character or other than numbers is entered it must not be accepted, like it must not be visible in textField.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to remove non-numeric digits, for showing a numeric keyboard and/or for enforcing a valid phone number to be typed (and formatting it consequently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set textfield keyboard type is Phone pad

or

Make a macro

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS @"0123456789."
```

And use it

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

if (textField==textFieldAmount)
{
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't work if the phone number has `+(country code) 10-digit no`.. so, it'll be nice to have `regular expressions`

Comment: @MKR  it work your have to add + in Acceptable character plz check .

Comment: @Kalpesh you are right, i just said instead of using `CharacterSet` you may also implement using `regular expressions`.

Comment: I feel this is the best answer I have seen even for number validation...

Answer (score 0):

@user3291536,
Better to try or search first, then post your query.
Anyway follow these links,

[Validating phone number in uitextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357432/validating-phone-number-in-uitextfield)

[UITextField for Phone Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246439/uitextfield-for-phone-number)

[how to perform validation on textfield for phone number entered by user in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919288/how-to-perform-validation-on-textfield-for-phone-number-entered-by-user-in-iphon)